# Interact with form while working in the background

Tags: vb.net

The goal is that the form should still be clickable while the code runs (mainly to be able to break the code) AND keeps getting updated by the running code at the same time. First part works, not the second part.

```
Public Class FormMain
    Public PleaseStopAll As Boolean
    Private Sub BreakCode_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BreakCode.Click
        PleaseStopAll = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Testeur_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Testeur.Click
        PleaseStopAll = False
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf LaunchTask, 0)
    End Sub

    Sub LaunchTask(o As Object)
        TheTask(Me)
    End Sub
    Public Sub ShowSomeMessage(msg As String
             Me.Displayer.text = msg
    End Sub
End Class

Module TaskDoer
    Sub TheTask(MyMenu As FormMain)
        For i As Integer = 0 To 42
            whatever() 'some tasks that cannot be interrupted safely
            MyMenu.ShowSomeMessage("task #" & CStr(i) & " over")  ' Here is the error
            If MyMenu.PleaseStopAll Then Exit For
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

The "status update" line tells that this task cannot interact with its parent task.
If I remove this line, the code runs just fine : code breaks when I ask to, and form remains clickable.

I tried with BackgroundWorker, but it needs actual progression to report something with ReportProgress (in increasing %) do I cannot just give a status (as string)

Comment: @Plutonix : here is the corrected question... Unfortunately I couldn't get BackgroundWorker to do the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass anything else via a variable or structure

```
 BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True '<Make sure this is set
 BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()



Private SomeStatus As String
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    SomeStatus = "Hello"
    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0)
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    ShowSOmeMEssage(SomeStatus)
End Sub
```

FYI: The progress thing is only so you can call a routine on the main UI thread. You can set as many thread-safe variables as you want on the form from within the backgroundworker. It's just updating the UI that's bothersome, though there is a workaround for that too.

Comment: It seems every progressChanged needs an ACTUAL change in progress. The "0" gives an exception: "no progression has been made".

Comment: Then make it another number

Comment: Then the exception will be on the second status update instead of the first one...

Comment: it should work fine with 0..make sure you flag the backgroundworker reports progress as in my edit.

Comment: Yes indeed, I don't know where I set the WorkerReportsProgress to false. It seems thje percentage can even go down (which is useful as I want different types of status reports, I can use the percentage as a code for the type)

Comment: btw: The progress thing is only so  you can call a routine on the main UI thread. You can set as many thread-safe variables as you want on the form from within the backgroundworker. It's just updating the UI that's bothersome, though there is a workaround for that too.